# Inconsistent results between tag search and tag merge search

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Searching for [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) gives me 200 results, almost all of which are really [android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity+android).

But Merge Tags gives me

[image]

Urp...Really?

Are there really 1976 deleted questions with the [activity] tag on them, and if so, how do I verify that, so that I know this is working correctly?  Do the deleted questions also get retagged?  Do they really have to be retagged if they're already deleted?

I don't really have a good solution for this.  The retagging could use some better filtering options, but I have no idea what those would look like.  Having the ability to filter the merge on another tag (in this case the **[android]** tag) comes to mind, but I don't know if that would be commonly useful or if it only applies to this particular situation.

Retagging 200 questions manually seems like a real pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `faq` tab selected.

The last tab selected on /questions is "sticky" between visits to that page (mine auto-selected `unanswered`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The only tab that seems to jibe with the numbers in the Merge Tags dialog is the "Active" tab.

Comment: Yes, that tab will show all the questions sorted in a specific order -- that number should match up with what appears in the mod tools.

Comment: spot on answer @Robert can you accept this.